# How to add one website to another website?

Tags: web-development

everyone.

I am working on a website based on **Yii2** through localhost. 
I want to add changes i made to the actual server. But i want to keep the old version and new version of the website working together.

What i mean: if i type

> http://url.com

i access the old version and when i type

> http://url.com/something

i access the new version.

How can i accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you be more specific? i really can't understand, what you want to achieve. both sites are working and editable on different urls, ok? one url points to one site, second url points to another one. what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, **make a subdomain**: `http://www.url.com` and `http://old.url.com`.

This way

- Your `document_root` variables will stay intact
- You don't need to prefix '/something/' to all your resources
- `http://www.url.com/something` remains accessable in case you (unforseenly) need it

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your web dir and copy entire page.
2. Make a new folder and name it `something`
3. Paste the entire web in that folder.
4. When you go on `www.example.com` you'll have one page, when you go on `www.example.com/something`, you'll go on this bacukped or newly created page.

BUT

when doing that and before doing any actual changes, backup your database also.

hope that helps.